# Is there a better way to write the function for my footer carousel dataobject

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have a dataobject that I use on my IndexPage page which works fine in its footer but it does not render on my other pages in the footer.

This is what I have tried so far in the default CWP PageController page and has made the data disappear from the index page (my IndexPage is extended by the CWP Page template):

```
 public function FooterFeedback()
   {
       $Footer = \SilverStripe\IndexPage\IndexPage::get();
           return $Footer;     

    }
```

This use to work for me in CWP SS3 using the PageController:

```
  public function FooterFeedback()
  {
        return Footer::get();
  }
```

I would like to add a feedback carousel to my footer across my website. 
In this carousel I have an Avitar (image), ClientAlias (TextField) and Feedback (HTMLEditorField).

I am still getting use to SS4 and I am not sure how to approach this problem. Any advice or help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how do I specify an image field in a dataobject  

$Footer = \SilverStripe\IndexPage\IndexPage::get();

Comment: In your SS4 example you are executing `IndexPage::get();`, have you removed the `Footer` data object, or why do you query the `IndexPage`? 

Also it would be easier to help you if you could provide more code from your classes, e.g. the `IndexPage` and `Footer` class.

Comment: Hi Conny, I have a simple footer data object associated with  the index page and it works fine if I don't have this function but I want to add the data object to the other pages. I am not sure how to do that. I don't have any other classes for the footer.

Comment: Couldn't the Footer DataObject be a singleton object and live by itself (not related to a page)? Then you could add a `getFooter` method on your root PageController, so all custom page controllers inherit that method. 

The `getFooter` method could like this `return Footer::get()->first()`, then in your template you can do `<% if $Footer %><% with $Footer %>...`

Comment: Hi Conny, I have made the footer into a page with a dataobject so it is now not part of the index page. This is what I have tried to use on my pageController: public function FooterFeedback()
 {
    $Footer = \SilverStripe\Page\FooterPage::get()->first();
       return $Footer;    

 }    I am not sure what to do because I have tried a combination of things but I can't seem to get it working. I also use this on my template page:    <% if $Footer %>
       
        <% loop $FooterFeedback %>

Comment: You can only use `<% loop $FooterFeedback %>` in the template if you return an array-/data list from the `getFooter` method. Currently you return a `FooterPage` object through `FooterPage::get()->first();`. If your FooterPage has a `Feedback` items list, then you can do `<% if $Footer %> <% loop $Footer.Feedback %>$SomeFeedbackField...`. If this does not work could you update your question with examples on how your classes currently look like (with e.g. pseudocode)? It would help us a lot in order to know what data you're trying to display.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your time with this. will try to update the question with my code

Comment: Hi Connie, I created a new question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59276382/is-there-a-better-way-to-write-the-function-for-my-carousel-dataobject-in-my-foo